# Connect Azure container to two volumes/file shares

Tags: azure

The following command creates a container in Azure that is mapped to a file share/volume:

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest 
 --azure-file-volume-share-name myshare --azure-file-volume-account-name mystorageacct 
 --azure-file-volume-account-key mystoragekey --azure-file-volume-mount-path /mnt/azfile
```

But I need my container to be mapped to two volumes, not just one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if it is possible to do this via azure cli. I do know that you can do this through Azure Resource Manager Templates.

In this example, see how the container group has an array of *volumes*, while each container can have an array of *volume mounts*.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
    "name": "[parameters('ContainerGroupName')]",
    "location": "australiaeast",
    "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "[variables('managedIdentityId')]": {}
        }
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('managedIdentityId')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
         "containers": [
         {
             "name": "[parameters('ContainerGroupName')]",
             "properties": {
                 "image": "[parameters('SourceImage')]",
                 "ports": [{"port": 80},{"port": 443}],
                "environmentVariables": [],
                "resources": { "requests": { "memoryInGB": 1.5, "cpu": 1 } },
                 "volumeMounts": [
                       {
                         "name": "httpscertificatevolume",
                         "mountPath": "/https"
                       },
                      {
                        "name": "videofoldervolume",
                        "mountPath": "[variables('videoFolderMountPath')]"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [{
                        "name": "httpscertificatevolume",
                        "azureFile": {
                            "shareName": "[parameters('HttpsCertificateFileShare')]",
                            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('StorageAccountName')]",
                            "storageAccountKey" : "[parameters('StorageAccountKey')]"
                         }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "videofoldervolume",
                        "azureFile": {
                            "shareName": "[parameters('VideoFileShare')]",
                            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('StorageAccountName')]",
                            "storageAccountKey" : "[parameters('StorageAccountKey')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```